# Why are all cyclic groups countable?

Tags: group-theory

I'm new to group theory. Why are all cyclic groups countable? And does countable mean finite or denumerable?

Comment: The integers $\mathbb Z$ are cyclic, so cyclic does not imply finite.

Comment: Yes, countable includes finite, though a lot of people use it as shorthand for "countably infinite." In your problem, countable is being used properly, in its inclusive sense. Your proof should start with "Let $g$ be a generator of $G$."

Comment: With the answers given to you here's a continuation of this exercise: Show that all finitely generated groups are countable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Countable* here means *at most countably infinite*, i.e., either finite or countably infinite. Let $g$ be a generator of the cyclic group $G$; then $G=\langle g\rangle=\{g^n:n\in\Bbb Z\}$. Since $\Bbb Z$ is countably infinite, $G$ can be at most countably infinite even if the map $\Bbb Z\to G:n\mapsto g^n$ is not injective (one-to-one).

Comment: Possibly worth noting: this can't really be carried (meaningfully) beyond $\mathbb{Z}$ because the equivalence classes $(a,b)$ that define members of $\mathbb{Z}$ don't 'work' correctly for infinite ordinals (because of the non-commutativity of ordinal addition).

Comment: @StevenStadnicki It'd be great if you could elaborate on that in an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I would say that this is because the word generate here means the repeated or iterated group operation, i.e., a group $(G,*)$ is generated by a set $S$ ({$S=g$} here) if every element $g$ in $G$ can be obtained by the repeated operation of g with itself. This only makes sense for $1, 2,3$, etc. iterations or repeated operations; operating g with itself a non-integer number of times does not have a clear meaning unless you deal with, e.g., topological groups. In this context you have, e.g., 1-parameter groups you may in some sense say are cyclic: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-parameter_group